# Fish shell function behave differently when called using $TERM -e

Tags: terminal, fish, xclip

I have the following fish function, that passes a list of words to `fzf` and once I select one, it removes the line break from the end and send it to the clipboard.

```sh
function spell_checker
  fzf < /usr/share/dict/words | tr -d '\n' | xclip -selection clipboard
end
```

The functions works well when I call it directly, but what I want to do is to create a shortcut for it. I am using `$TERM -e fish -c spell_checker`, to open a terminal, run the program and then immediately close the terminal, but for some reason when I call the command it does not work as expected. It opens the terminal, shows me the fzf with the list of words, but it does not send it to the clipboard.

Any input on what could be causing this behaviour?

I tried a simple version of the function that simply sends something to the clipboard and it doesn't seem to work either. I tried with the terminals *st*, *alacritty* and *xterm* but they all behave the same.

Comment: Is there a particular reason this needs to be run in a new terminal and not the current one?

Comment: Yes, because I want to launch it from a keyboard shortcut